# Unaccent in Sequelize

Tags: node.js, postgresql, express, sequelize.js

I'm currently working in a project that uses ExpressJS, PostgreSQL and Sequelize as the ORM. I developed a search function that makes a query that searches items by name:

```
models.foo.findAll({
  where: {
    $or: [
      {name: {$ilike: keywords}},
      {searchMatches: {$contains: [keywords]}}
    ]
  },
  order: [['name', 'ASC']]
})
```

This works fine, but if the name contains an special character (like á, é, í, ó or ú) this query won't find it.

Is there a way to make the query search names with speacial characters in a meaningful sense? Like if I search the name "potato" the results "The potato", "Da potátos" and "We are the pótatóes" will come out, but not "We eat pátatos" (since á != o)

Comment: I'll just comment since I don't think my workaround is answer material. I tackled this issue before with sequelize and failed so I deviced a workaround function that created an array which contained as many elements as every single permutation of vowel and accent mark in a given string. This array would be used to build the `$or` array in the sequelize query.

Comment: @FranciscoFarías I posted an answer that could be useful for you.

Answer (score 7):

This can now be done without a completely RAW query, but using Sequelize's in built functions:

```
models.foo.findAll({
  where: Sequelize.where(
    Sequelize.fn('unaccent', Sequelize.col('name')), {
        [Op.iLike]:`%${keywords}%`
  }),
  order: [['name', 'ASC']]
})
```

Then ordering, associations etc. all work still as normal :).

Answer (score 4):

I finally found a valid solution. First I created the unaccent extension:

```
create extension unaccent;
```

Then I just used a raw query (I couldn't figure out how to build the query using Sequelize's way) like this:

```
models.sequelize.query(
    `SELECT
      *
    FROM
      "Foos"
    WHERE
      unaccent("name") ilike unaccent('${keywords}')          
      OR "searchMatches" @> ARRAY[unaccent('${keywords}')]::VARCHAR(255)[]
    ORDER BY
      "name" ASC`, {model: models.Foo})
```

And it works!

Answer (score 0):

A dictionary might be what you are looking for. Can basically be used to map synonyms and exclude common elements from indexes (e.g. "a" and "the" from English text), amongst other things.

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/textsearch-dictionaries.html

Comment: I don't think that is what I'm looking for, since I can't map every word that can be used as a name because the users can come up with new words as a name.

Comment: @Potray There are pre-built ones you can use. Seems like you found a different solution though, so well done :)

Answer (score 0):

In my case I solved this question using the Sequelize.literal and COLLATE that way:

```
where: Sequelize.literal(`name COLLATE Latin1_general_CI_AI like '%${keywords}%' COLLATE Latin1_general_CI_AI`)
```

That way, removing the accents on both sides.